# Cast generic class to different type

Tags: c#, class, generics, casting

**NOTE** : I am going to simplify the structure and contents of the class, it is much more complex in reality but the rest of it isn't necessary to the issue at hand.

I have the following (simplified) class structure :

```
public abstract class Config
{
    // A number of abstract parameters and special abstract methods
}

public class GenericConfig<T> : Config
{
    private DataType configDataType;
    public DataType ConfigDataType
    {
        get { /* A get function */ }
        set { /* A set function */ }
    }
    public T InitialValue { get; set; }
    public T MinValue { get; set; }
    public T MaxValue { get; set; }
    // Overridden parameters and methods
}

public enum DataType
{
    Int,
    Bool,
    Float,
    String,
    DateTime
}
```

When I instantiate a `Config` object, it looks like this :

`Config configInstance = new GenericConfig<int>(..., ConfigDataType=0, ...)`

What I would like to be able to do is cast the int type to float or anything from a method call. Something like the following (I'd preferably like to follow my enum types):

`configInstance.CastType("Float")` **OR** `configInstance.CastType(2)` which would give me the equivalent of :

`Config configInstance = new GenericConfig<float>(..., ConfigDataType=2, ...)`

Is this even remotely possible or is it something that should be avoided ?

Comment: What is the usage of generic parameter `T` in `GenericConfig`?

Comment: I'll edit and add its use ! Apologies

Comment: What should happen with min, max and initial values after the cast? Do they need to be updated as well? Because `int` and `float` have a different boundaries. Also, why config type is set to 0 here `new GenericConfig<float>(..., ConfigDataType=0, ...)`? Maybe 2?

Comment: Yes you're right for both points, the cast should affect the `T` as a global type and therefore affect each property based on it (and yes it should be a 2, will change).

Comment: You can convert most of the types using [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=netcore-3.1) interface. Except `DateTime`, because cast to/from numeric types throws an exception

Comment: Would I simply need to call `Convert.ChangeType(configInstance, System.Double)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may consider to rethink or improve your design (why `ConfigDataType` is nedeed) but you can use operator explicit casting like this:

```
static public explicit operator GenericConfig<int>(GenericConfig<T> value)
{
  if ( typeof(T) is int ) return (GenericConfig<int>)value;
  return null;
}

static public explicit operator GenericConfig<float>(GenericConfig<T> value)
{
  if ( typeof(T) is float ) return (GenericConfig<float>)value;
  return null;
}
```

Create a new instance and process the conversion by copy instead of returning null.

*Usage:*

```
Config v1 = new GenericConfig<int>();
Config v2 = (GenericConfig<float>)v1;
```